# Colocar contenido antes de la última etiqueta `</p>` mediante PHP

Tags: php, google-calendar

Estoy generando un contenido HTML obtenido de un calendario de Google. En el detalle de cada evento del calendario tengo un contenido HTML el cual obtengo y renderizo sin ningún problema en PHP mediante la API de Google Calendar.

Ahora bien, hay un contenido que no está en el detalle de cada evento y que quiero agregar al leer los datos mediante la API.

Este es el ejemplo de la lectura de un día concreto:

```
<h3>
  <font color="red">Lunes 4</font>
</h3>
<h4>FERIAS ANTERIORES A LA EPIFANíA: 4 DE ENERO</h4>
<p>Misa de feria (blanco).</p>
<p>
  <b>Misal:</b>
  <br>
  Antífonas y oraciones propias, Prefacio de Navidad.
</p>
<p>
  <b>Leccionario</b>
  (volumen II):
  <br>
  – 1 Jn 3, 7-10.
  <i>No puede pecar, porque ha nacido de Dios.</i>
  <br>
  – Sal 97, 1-2ab. 7-8a. 8b-9.
  <i>Los confines de la tierra han contemplado la salvación de nuestro Dios.</i>
  <br>
  – Jn 1, 35-42.
  <i>Hemos encontrado al Mesías.</i>
  <br>
</p>
<p>
  <b>Liturgia de Las Horas:</b>
  <br>
  Oficio de feria (4 de enero, ferias anteriores a la Epifanía). Si se hace el bienal, año impar.
</p>
<p>
  <b>Recursos:</b>
  <br>
  –
  <a href="https://www.deiverbum.org/homilias_tiempo-navidad-ferias-antes-de-la-epifania_dia-04-de-enero/">Homilías</a>
  <br>
  –
  <a href="https://www.deiverbum.org/jn-01_35-42/">Comentarios al Evangelio</a>
  <br>
  –
  <a href="https://deiverbum.org/liturgia/misa/lecturas/id/406">Textos bíblicos</a>
</p>
<a href="https://www.deiverbum.org/santos/01/04/" rel="nofollow">– Santo del día</a>
```

Si observan al final, este es el contenido que no existe en el evento:

```
<a href="https://www.deiverbum.org/santos/01/04/" rel="nofollow">– Santo del día</a>
```

Lo que yo quiero es **agregarlo dentro del último `</p>`, al final**, para que quede así:

```
<p>
  <b>Recursos:</b>
  <br>
  –
  <a href="https://www.deiverbum.org/homilias_tiempo-navidad-ferias-antes-de-la-epifania_dia-04-de-enero/">Homilías</a>
  <br>
  –
  <a href="https://www.deiverbum.org/jn-01_35-42/">Comentarios al Evangelio</a>
  <br>
  –
  <a href="https://deiverbum.org/liturgia/misa/lecturas/id/406">Textos bíblicos</a>
  <a href="https://www.deiverbum.org/santos/01/04/" rel="nofollow">– Santo del día</a>
</p>
```

Este es mi código actual:

```
foreach ($results->getItems() as $event) {
    $start = $event->start->dateTime;
    if (empty($start)) {
        $start = $event->start->date;
    }
    $start=new DateTime($start);
    $html.="<h3><font color=\"red\">".$longDays[$start->format("w")]." ".$start->format("j")."</font></h3>";
    $html.="<h4>".strtoupper($event->getSummary())."</h4>";
       
    $html.=$event->getDescription();
    /*
        Contenido que no está en la descripción del evento
        pero que quiero agregar aquí
    */
    $mm=$start->format("m");
    $dd=$start->format("d");
    $html.="<a href=\"https://www.deiverbum.org/santos/$mm/$dd/\" rel=\"nofollow\">– Santo del día</a><br><hr>";
}
print html_entity_decode($html);
```

¿De qué modo podría poner el último enlace generado dentro de cada evento dentro del último `<p> ... CONTENIDO-AQUÍ</p>`?

Quisiera una solución donde se manipulen los datos lo menos posible. Pensé en agregar al description de cada evento un carácter especial y hacer un reemplazo, pero no es una solución óptima, porque implicaría agregar algo extraño a los eventos (el Calendario sirve también como calendario a ser visualizado en otros lugares/dispositivos).

Comment: ¿La "sección recursos" siempre tiene el mismo formato y se encuentra siempre al final? Si la respuesta es si, con un [`substr`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.substr.php) podrías solucionarlo

Comment: Hola @Marcos. Sí, la sección `Recursos` es lo último que hay en cada detalle de cada evento.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Teniendo en consideración que:

> la sección Recursos es lo último que hay en cada detalle de cada evento.

Entonces, podrías hacer lo siguiente:

1. Con [`substr`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.substr.php) borramos último el `</p>` en la variable `$html`.
2. Agregamos a la variable `$html` la cadena deseada
3. Finalmente a la variable `$html` agregamos la cadena `</p>` (*la cual sacamos en el paso 1*)

#### Ejemplo:

```
foreach ($results->getItems() as $event) {
    $start = $event->start->dateTime;
    if (empty($start)) {
        $start = $event->start->date;
    }
    $start=new DateTime($start);
    $html.="<h3><font color=\"red\">".$longDays[$start->format("w")]." ".$start->format("j")."</font></h3>";
    $html.="<h4>".strtoupper($event->getSummary())."</h4>";
       
    $html.=$event->getDescription();

    $mm=$start->format("m");
    $dd=$start->format("d");

    // ACA - Manipulamos el contenido
    $tag = '</p>';
    $html = substr(rtrim($html), 0, -strlen($tag));
    $html .= "<a href=\"https://www.deiverbum.org/santos/$mm/$dd/\" rel=\"nofollow\">– Santo del día</a>\n";
    $html .= $tag;
}
print html_entity_decode($html);
```

Comment: Funciona perfectamente, muchas gracias. Solamente, para no modificar de nuevo la cadena, en vez de esto: `$html .= $tag;` agregué la etiqueta `</p>` al final de la penúltima línea (de paso quité el salto `\n` que había ahí).